# Why does Failover Cluster Manager GUI not reflect our Powershell input?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, nodes, cluster-computing, failover

We are running the following commands in this order;

```
Stop-ClusterResource resource-name -Cluster cluster-name
```

This is successful and reports the resource as stopped.

```
Start-ClusterResource resource-name -Cluster cluster-name
```

This is successful and reports the resource as online, however the FCM GUI looks like the below picture despite running the Get-ClusterResource command which reports it as Online.

[Discrepancy between CLI response & GUI feedback.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpCwp.png)

When stopping and starting a resource via the FCM GUI it works as intended.

Comment: Does it stay that way in the GUI _forever_ or does it eventually show the resource as online?

Comment: It stays that way forever.